# How to implement a queue in Go?

Tags: data-structures, go, queue

The current Go library doesn't provide the queue container.
To implement a simple queue, I use circle array as the underlying data structure.
It follows algorithms mentioned in TAOCP:

```
Insert Y into queue X: X[R]<-Y; R<-(R+1)%M; if R=F then OVERFLOW.
Delete Y from queue X: if F=R then UNDERFLOW; Y<-X[F]; F<-(F+1) % M.
F: Front, R: Rear, M: Array length.
```

Following is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Queue struct {
    len        int 
    head, tail int 
    q          []int
}

func New(n int) *Queue {
    return &Queue{n, 0, 0, make([]int, n)} 
}

func (p *Queue) Enqueue(x int) bool {
    p.q[p.tail] = x 
    p.tail = (p.tail + 1) % p.len
    return p.head != p.tail
}

func (p *Queue) Dequeue() (int, bool) {
    if p.head == p.tail {
        return 0, false
    }   
    x := p.q[p.head]
    p.head = (p.head + 1) % p.len
    return x, true
}

func main() {
    q := New(10)
    for i := 1; i < 13; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, q.Enqueue(i))
    }   
    fmt.Println()
    for i := 1; i < 13; i++ {
        fmt.Println(q.Dequeue())
    }   
}
```

But the output is obviously wrong:

1 true
2 true
3 true
4 true
5 true
6 true
7 true
8 true
9 true
10 false
11 true
12 true

11 true
12 true
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false
0 false

I think I need one more field to make the code work properly.
What do you suggest?

The improved code has a small shortcoming: an array of size n can contain only n-1 elements.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Queue struct {
    len        int 
    head, tail int 
    q          []int
}

func New(n int) *Queue {
    return &Queue{n, 0, 0, make([]int, n)} 
}

func (p *Queue) Enqueue(x int) bool {
    p.q[p.tail] = x 
    ntail := (p.tail + 1) % p.len
    ok := false
    if ntail != p.head {
        p.tail = ntail
        ok = true
    }   
    return ok
}

func (p *Queue) Dequeue() (int, bool) {
    if p.head == p.tail {
        return 0, false
    }   
    x := p.q[p.head]
    p.head = (p.head + 1) % p.len
    return x, true
}

func main() {
    q := New(10)
    for i := 1; i < 13; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, q.Enqueue(i))
    }   
    fmt.Println()
    for i := 1; i < 13; i++ {
        fmt.Println(q.Dequeue())
    }   
}
```

Comment: Now you do not need any of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31127526/1090562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Enqueue` fails, you're *still* incrementing `p.tail`, so next time it will appear not to fail -- that explains the single `false` in your first loop (and messes everything up for the second one).  The original algorithm says `OVERFLOW` meaning "give everything up", not "just keep going as if nothing untowards happened";-).

All you need to do is decrement `p.tail` if you've checked that failure's occurring -- or put the incremented value in a local temporary and move it to `p.tail` only if failure is *not* occurring, that may be more elegant.  This way, the failing `Enqueue` does *not* enqueue the new value, but the queue itself (without that overflowing value) is still semantically intact and correct for future operations.

Answer (score 11):

You do not need all this hustle in any reasonable go version (after 1.x). Everything can be achieved with [slices](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

`queue := []int{}`

**Add to a queue:**

`queue = append(queue, 6)`

**Pop from a queue:**

```
el := queue[0]
queue = queue[1:]
```

---

Here is implementation that shows that pop does not take a lot of time (in fact here it is shorter than push because in my opinion of reallocation of memory when the queue is growing).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    n := 10000000
    queue := []int{1, 2, 3}

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        queue = append(queue, i)
    }
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elapsed)

    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        _ = queue[0]
        queue = queue[1:]
    }
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elapsed)
    fmt.Println(queue)
}
```

On my machine the numbers are:

```
216.611664ms
13.441106ms
```

From **@DaveC**'s comment:

> This is simple and works very well for everything except critical code
>   where allocations (pressure on the garbage collector) is
>   undesirable.Two things to note, first it does keep re-allocating the
>   underlying array on push (although efficiently and not on every call)
>   and pop doesn't free any space until that happens. This leads to the
>   second thing, if (as is common) the queue contains a pointer to
>   something, then it's good to do queue[0] = nil; queue = queue[1:] to
>   have the queue stop referencing the pointer right away.

Answer (score 4):

A buffered channel makes a fine queue, though it has a fixed maximum queue length, chosen at creation time. A channel has the useful property that dequeues are threadsafe (your code isn't).

Answer (score 2):

It's true that there's no package called queue, but either [vector](http://golang.org/pkg/container/vector/) or [list](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/) would make fine queues. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818852/can-anybody-suggest-go-lang-container-for-simple-and-fast-fifo-stack/).

Comment: vector is probably not good, because inserting or removing things from the beginning entails shifting all the elements, which is terribly inefficient

Comment: @newacct Thanks, you're absolutely right. list would definitely be better in this case, but vector would still work without modification -- just not very efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

> First you need to create a struct for **Queue** for holding queue properties. Then create a **initQueue** function to initialize default values, which will also take memory size from the user. Create a function to **enqueue** values, create function to **dequeue** values. Create a display function to **display** queues values.

```
type Queue struct {
    front  int
    rear   int
    size   int
    QArray []int
}

func (q *Queue) initQueue(size int) {
    q.size = size
    q.QArray = make([]int, q.size)
    q.front = -1
    q.rear = -1
}

func (q *Queue) enqueue(value int) {
    if q.rear == q.size-1 {
        fmt.Println("Queue is Full")
        return
    } else {
        q.rear++
        q.QArray[q.rear] = value
    }
}

func (q *Queue) dequeue() int {
    var x int = -1
    if q.front == q.rear {
        fmt.Println("Queue is Empty!")
    } else {
        q.front++
        x = q.QArray[q.front]
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I modify the original implementation to make a dynamic queue. I.e. when the queue fills up it will allocate a larger queue and move all the items over.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Queue struct {
    len        uint
    head, tail uint
    q          []int
}

func NextPowerOfTwo(v uint) uint {
    if v == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    v--
    v |= v >> 1
    v |= v >> 2
    v |= v >> 4
    v |= v >> 8
    v |= v >> 16
    v++
    return v
}

func NewQueue(n uint) *Queue {
    n = NextPowerOfTwo(n)
    if n < 4 {
        n = 4
    }
    println("create queue of", n)
    return &Queue{n, 0, 0, make([]int, n)}
}

func (p *Queue) Resize() {
    if p.head == (p.tail + 1) % p.len {
        new_len := p.len * 2;
        new_q := make([]int, new_len)
        // currently there are (len - 1) items in the queue
        var i uint
        for i = 0; i < p.len - 1; i++ {
            n, _ := p.Dequeue()
            new_q[i] = n
        }
        p.q = new_q
        p.head, p.tail = 0, p.len - 1
        p.len = new_len
        println("queue resized to ", p.len)
    }
}

func (p *Queue) Enqueue(x int) {
    p.Resize();
    p.q[p.tail] = x
    p.tail = (p.tail + 1) % p.len
}

func (p *Queue) Dequeue() (int, bool) {
    if p.head == p.tail {
        return -1, false
    }
    x := p.q[p.head]
    p.head = (p.head + 1) % p.len
    return x, true
}

func main() {
    q := NewQueue(1)
    for i := 1; i < 13; i++ {
        q.Enqueue(2 * i + 1)
        println("enqueued item ", i)
    }
    println("** queue content **")
    for i := 1; i < 13 + 1; i++ {
        fmt.Println(q.Dequeue())
    }
}
```