# Queue of structs in Go

Tags: go, struct, queue

I have been learning Go, and I was doing a BFS puzzle with it. The queue implementation I decided on is:

```
//define the queue for our BFS algo as frontier.
type frontier struct {
    queue []*graphNode
}

func (F *frontier) buildFrontier() {
    F.queue = make([]*graphNode, 0, 1000)
}

func (F *frontier) pop() (g *graphNode) {
    if F.isEmpty() {
        panic("pop on empty queue!")
    }
    temp := F.queue[0]
    F.queue = F.queue[1:]
    return temp
}

func (F *frontier) push(g *graphNode) {
    F.queue = append(F.queue, g)
}

func (F *frontier) isEmpty() bool {
    return len(F.queue) == 0
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this a good implementation? Documentation on queues in go is sparse, and in general there are some old posts about vectors, and a list seems to have too much overhead (not that it matters for my case, but I'm trying to do it the best way possible).
2. Why does the call to an object (in this case the struct pointer F *frontier) have to be a pointer? It seems like the way the syntax works that it should be a default for a pointer, not explicit (i.e. why would you ever not want to use a pointer in these instances?)

MODIFIED CIRCULAR VERSION:

```
//define the queue for our BFS algo as frontier.
type frontier struct {
    queue                []*graphNode
    size, head, capacity int
}

func (F *frontier) buildFrontier() {
    F.capacity = 1
    F.queue = make([]*graphNode, F.capacity)
    F.size = 0
    F.head = 0
}

func (F *frontier) pop() (g *graphNode) {
    if F.isEmpty() {
        panic("pop on empty queue!")
    }
    F.size = (F.size - 1)
    temp := F.queue[F.head]
    F.head = (F.head + 1) % F.capacity
    return temp
}

func (F *frontier) push(g *graphNode) {
    if F.isFull() {
        newSlice := make([]*graphNode, F.capacity*2)
        copy(newSlice, F.queue)
        F.queue = newSlice
        F.capacity *= 2
    }
    F.queue[(F.head+F.size)%F.capacity] = g
    F.size = (F.size + 1)
}

func (F *frontier) isEmpty() bool {
    return F.size == 0
}
func (F *frontier) isFull() bool {
    return F.size == F.capacity
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a queue in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042329/how-to-implement-a-queue-in-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like your implementation will work, but it will end up being a bit inefficient. At the beginning, `queue` is a slice with capacity 1000. That means that the underlying array can hold 1000 elements. Every time you call `pop`, you're moving the beginning of the queue one element further down that array, thus reducing the capacity by 1. Eventually, the capacity will be insufficient to hold a new element when you call `push`, even though there may not be many (or any) elements in the queue. That will cause a new array to be allocated when `append` is called. No matter what the pattern of `push` and `pop` calls is, the array will be repeatedly reallocated, even if it never holds anywhere near 1000 elements. I would suggest using a linked list for this, either the one in the `list` package or one of your own design.
2. The receiver needs to be a pointer if the function will modify the receiver's value or if the receiver object is used in other places and the value must be shared. Otherwise, it doesn't need to be a pointer. You may want to make the receiver a pointer anyway if the value is large so that it doesn't have to be copied. (The receiver behaves like any other function parameter and the same considerations apply.)

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's exactly the kind of mistake I was hoping someone could point out, and its obvious to me now.... Ive modified the answer to include a circular implementation that self expands, would you be so kind as to provide thoughts on it as well?

Comment: The way `push` works doesn't look right. I think the index for the new element should be `(F.head+F.size)%F.capacity`. I've only taken a quick look at this so there may be other issues. This seems overly complex for a queue.  A linked list would be a lot simpler.

Comment: you're right about push, again fixed above. It passed my unit test, there weren't enough deletions to test the wrap around. Thanks. Its complex to avoid the reallocation, and while here it starts with a cap of 1, the intent is to make it much larger to avoid copies at the expense of memory (not a limiting factor for the problem).