# LIFO container in Go

Tags: go

I need to use LIFO stack container with push and pop operations, but `container` package doesn't have one. Is it supposed to be writen ad-hoc by every programmer, or there is a way to use other data structure as stack (like list in python)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818852/can-anybody-suggest-go-lang-container-for-simple-and-fast-fifo-stack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built-in stack type in Go or the standard libraries. However, you can add Push and Pop methods to a slice pretty simply (not unlike the existing methods on lists in python).

```golang
type Stack []YourType

func (s *Stack) Push(v YourType) {
    *s = append(*s, v)
}

func (s *Stack) Pop() YourType {
    ret := (*s)[len(*s)-1]
    *s = (*s)[0 : len(*s)-1]

    return ret
}
```

Pretty straightforward

Comment: But only partially an answer.

Comment: @nemo I didn't feel there was much more to say, short of an overblown explanation of slice/pointer semantics.

Comment: Hmm, I would've expected something like `yes you have to implement it yourself. For example: ....`. Just posting code gives the intention of not having read the question at all and just throwing code around. But maybe it is just me

Comment: see my reply，your code is not good,for append is slow and won't release the heap memory after pop,use container/list is better

Answer (score 4):

stack is a subset of list，golang has container/list library，which is simple for implement a stack，here is an example。

```
//last in first out
    stack := list.New()
    //stack push use PushBack
    for i:=0;i<100;i++ {
        stack.PushBack(i)
    }
    //stack get top use stack.Back()
    //stack pop use stack.Remove(stack.Back())
    //stack isEmpty use stack.Back() == nil 
    for stack.Back()!=nil {
        fmt.Println(stack.Back().Value)
        stack.Remove(stack.Back())
    }
```

Comment: I had no idea about the `container/list` package. I've been implementing push and pop for a long time. Much better to use something like this from the standard library. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `container/list` is an implementation of a doubly linked list, and is not typed in the traditional sense. It uses a generic `Element`, which is a struct with `Value` field of type `any`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `container` package in the stdlib. Yet, LIFO is just a stack, it's easily modelled by, for example, a slice. Hence no stdlib LIFO container.

Comment: @Lazin: That's not a package.

Comment: Yes there is "container" package and under this there is "container/list".